# Is it possible to block images from a specific URL using the “hosts” file?

Tags: browser, blocking, hosts-file, img

I want to block images in a website which is often unimportant ads uploaded to their server or host.

Using `inspect element` I noticed the all these images was named with `ad-[some number].jpg`.

I can’t use any extensions in my browser so is it possible to do something like that using the “hosts” file or any local way.

I have tried `ad-*.jpg` but it doesnt make any sense.

Comment: Use Ad block software in browser. In hosts file you can block entire hostname (to be resolved)

Comment: i want it to be global for all users with all browers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to block images in a website....so how could i do that using hosts file or any local way.

**The Hosts file won't work for you. It blocks *everything* served by a server.**

The `HOSTS` file enables you to change the IP address your computer uses to connect to certain hosts. For example the following entry:

```
www.example.com       127.0.0.1
```

will cause your computer to direct all connections targeting the Internet host `www.example.com` to **127.0.0.1**.

However, what you're trying to do is block requests for *resources* on the Internet host, such as *www.example.com**/ads/somead.jpg***, without blocking other content on the host. This cannot be done with the Hosts file; it's all or nothing.

> I can't use any extensions

**Bummer.**

It's no good that the solution to your problem is to use browser extensions like [AdBlock Plus](https://adblockplus.org). That's really the best approach when trying to implement something on your local machine to block unwanted ads.

If you happen to have control of the router that serves your network, it may have some options for blocking unwanted content at the network level.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with hosts file by mapping a hostname to localhost but you need to know what server's hostname is requested to display these ads. I would suggest to use Ad block software which would do the job better.

Anyhow if you manage to get ad server hostname or ip you just have to do as I said above :

```
/etc/hosts:

ad_server's_hostname localhost
ad_server's_ip       localhost
```

Comment: This will block entire server, not only the images!

Comment: You mean server that hold the website Omar mah is navigating on or the server that provides ads ?

Comment: It can be. You want to read some news site w/o seeing ads

Comment: yeah guys I only need to block images for example: www.example.com/images/ad-num.jpg i need to block images from that directory which hold the ad prefix.